# When I disconnect camera in device, occur nullpointerException on android

Tags: java, android

recently I use `WebRTC`

my device basically have 2 cameras

when I disconnect 1 camera.

occur `nullPointerException`
I think need `Camera null check`

but I don't know where null check part

I add gradle `compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9127@aar'
            compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'`

and my `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   String FrontCamaera = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();

   VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(FrontCamera);
   if (capturer == null || capturer.equals("") == true) {
   // I don't know null check....
   }
    MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints); //NPE

   .
   .
   }
```

VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice()

```
 public static String getNameOfFrontFacingDevice() {
    for(int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++i) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();

        try {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if(info.facing == 1) {
                return getDeviceName(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception var3) {
            Log.e("VideoCapturerAndroid", "getCameraInfo failed on index " + i, var3);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

VideoCapturerAndroid.create()

```
  public static VideoCapturerAndroid create(String name) {
    VideoCapturer capturer = VideoCapturer.create(name);
    return capturer != null?(VideoCapturerAndroid)capturer:null;
}
```

logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(PeerConnectionFactory.java:111)
      at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.BlackEyeActivity.onCreate(BlackEyeActivity.java:226)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

if you need more information. please comment me

in other words. 
if I  disconnect camera in my device
I want app not died..

thanks.